# JSON JQuery Flickr

Tags: jquery, json, rss

I have this JQuery expression

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photoset.gne?set=72157607523855079&nsid=9298216@N08&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data){
  $.each(data.items, function(i,item)
  {
  $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images").wrap("<a href='" + item.link + "'></a>");
});
```

Which pulls the appropriate images from my Flickr acccount, but how do I get and the **image** title and the **image** "content"?

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide the extra options that you want to retrieve as a parameter to the API call for things other than the title.  The title seems to be provided by default, so you'd refer to it as `item.title`.  See the [documentation](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getPhotos.html) at Flickr.  You might also want to look at the returned data in Firefox/Firebug if you have further questions about the structure of the returned objects.

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photoset.gne?'
   + 'set=72157607523855079&nsid=9298216@N08&lang=en-us'
   + '&extras=tags,media,date_taken'
   + '&format=json&jsoncallback=?", ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){       

    var id='9298216@N08';
    var limit ='20';

    // Flickr Photostream feed link.
    $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=" + id + "&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?", 

    function(data){$.each(data.items, 

    function(i,item){

        // Number of thumbnails to show.            
        if(i < limit){

        // Create images and append to div id flickr and wrap link around the image.
        $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m.replace('_m', '_s')).appendTo("#flickr").wrap("<a href='" + item.media.m.replace('_m', '_z') + "' name='"+ item.link + "' title='" +  item.title +"'></a>");


        }

    }); 

    }); 

    });
```

That should do the trick using jQuery, Simply create a div with an id flickr and images will be added to this div.

Full answer and example here http://jsfiddle.net/C7guQ/1/